# MATLAB- Renaming issue of heaviside.m

Tags: matlab

1) `int((  heaviside(sym('t')) ),0,0.5 )` works perfectly but when I edit the in-built **MATLAB** file heaviside.m and rename it as my_heaviside.m and then call it in the command window as
`int((  my_heaviside(sym('t'))   ),0,0.5 )`   it shows error.

2) How to write the following piecewise function with the help of heaviside: 
`f(x)= 1, 2<=x <3`  & 0 elsewhere. Note that at `x=2`, I require `f(x)= 1` and  at `x=3`, I require `f(x)= 0`.

3) I want that the `f(x)` in point no. 2 should be defined in such a way that it can be symbolically integrate like in point 1.

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: The error message is:                                                              Error using symengine (line 56)
Unable to prove '0 < t' literally. To test the
statement mathematically, use isAlways.

Error in sym/subsindex (line 1551)
                X =
                find(mupadmex('symobj::logical',A.s,9))
                - 1;

Error in my_heaviside (line 4)
Y(X > 0) = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the function name inside `my_heaviside.m` file from heaviside to my_heaviside.

Comment: I have changed the name inside also like here and saved as  my_heaviside.m :                                                           function Y = my_heaviside(X)

Y = zeros(size(X));
Y(X > 0) = 1;
eng = symengine;
if strcmp(eng.kind,'maple')
    Y(X == 0) = nan;
else
    Y(X == 0) = 0;
end

Answer (score 0):

If you use a breakpoint in the `heaviside` function, then you will see that Matlab never actually goes into the function when evaluating `heaviside(t)`. Why?  What should be the output of `heaviside(t)`?  It is supposed to be `heaviside(t)`!  What it actually does is  it goes to the method `heaviside` inside of the `sym` class definition, the output of that function is just `mupadmex('symobj::map',t.s,'heaviside')` which is just another name for the `heaviside` of `t` (here `s` is a private property of a `sym` object).

Also when Matlab tries to integrate the `heaviside` function, it cannot integrate it from first principles by looking at the structure of the `mfile`, but it uses theorems to evaluate expressions containing it; thus one cannot hope to edit the actual mupad file for `heaviside` and expect Matlab to find the correct integral.